# Raster Data set Size on Disc (ArcGIS)

Tags: raster, arcgis-desktop, data

I have just converted a vector dataset of census tracts into a raster data set for an assignment. I can see the uncompressed size of the dataset in layer properties dialog box. But the assignment specifically asks about the uncompressed size AS WELL AS size on the disc. I checked the size on disc by locating the raster files in geodatabase in my C drive but it shows 0 KB. How can I find the size of raster dataset on disc? The uncompressed size in this example is 72.9 mb. Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you saved the raster into a geodatabase. Your professor may have assumed you would save it into a separate raster/image file. Try running the conversion again but remove the geodatabase name, and give a raster format extension like .tif or .jpg to the name.

Comment: Thanks Mckennedy for your suggestion. But please note that I am using Feature to Raster Tool (under conversion tools in toolbox) and there is no option to save in tif or jpeg. However, as per your suggestion I changed the location of my file and added .jpeg in file name but there came an error which said that jpeg extension is invalid for output raster format. I checked the file size and saw the same file with different extensions like .aux, .ovr, .vat, etc. None of them is greater than 2KB in size (I am using ArcGIS 10.1)

Comment: Saving as TIF or JPEG formats, both of which support compression, might be defeating the purpose of the exercise. The professor likely intends the raster to be saved in *native* ArcInfo format, which will be a folder consisting of about nine related files. Look for one named `w001001.adf`: that contains the data.